# How to convert simple sql query in magento to fetch record collection

Tags: sql, magento

How to write this query

```
SELECT * FROM vendors WHERE FIND_IN_SET(  'Family Events', bank_acc_name )
```

into this format

```
$vendors = Mage::getModel('vendor/vendor')->getCollection()
->addFieldToFilter(category_name, $value);
```

I want to fetch records from collection in magento

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Mage::getModel('vendor/vendor')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter($category_name, array('finset' => $value));
```